# TDS Not Deploying Template Changes

Tags: tds, fieldtype, serialization

We are having difficulties getting an update to a Template to deploy properly. Take the example structure below:

```
 - Template Item
 - - Section Item
 - - - Field Item 1
 - - - Field Item 2
```

The items that we need an update are `Field Item 1` and `Field Item 2`. In a previous deployment, these Template Fields were set to `Shared`. Now, however, we need to 'unshare' these fields.

We are using Update Packages coupled with Sitecore Package Deployer for pushing item changes.

**Sitecore 8.2u5**

**TDS 5.7.0.7**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is inherent with the way Sitecore handles checkbox fields and how it serializes items.

## Checkbox Field

Checkbox fields in Sitecore can have 3 values:

- Blank (not set)
- 0 (unchecked)
- 1 (checked)

`Blank` and `0` are interpreted as the same value of `false` value when reading the fields on an item through the Item API.

## Serialization

During serialization (the technique TDS uses for reading items) a field with a blank value is not written to disk. Only fields with values `0` or `1` are written out. *This is a Sitecore-ism.* TDS uses the Sitecore API for serialization.

## Problem

When using the UI (in Content Editor for example) and checking/unchecking a checkbox, the field value toggles between `Blank` and `1`.

## Solution

The only way to achieve a value of `0` is to select Raw Values from the View tab. Enter a `0` into the checkbox field and save the item. Re-sync in TDS and if you inspect the corresponding `*.item` file, you will see the field listed properly.

Now when the Update Package is installed, it will explicitly set the value and *uncheck* the field.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it does trigger this. Changing the field sharing on any template field *must* go via `TemplateManager.ChangeFieldSharing` - and this method triggers the job on the DataProvider level. I would consider it a serious bug, if TDS was to bypass this.